# Root Mean Square Error with Matlab

Tags: matlab, threshold

I have an image.How can I do RMSE?

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
```

Comment: Please post the error message you receive :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a single number that represents the RMSE of the whole image, try `rmse = sqrt(mean((I(:)-A(:)).^2))` that gives you a single number.

If you're looking to plot RMSE for each pixel, then there's no need to take the mean. Moreover, you need to convert A and I to a float matrix so `sqrt` doesn't return an error. Try `sqrt((double(I-A)).^2)`.